# PHP image not showing up

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart

i downloaded a tutorial of the web which contained a php shopping cart and an mysql database with the tables already built in. I managed to intergrate that whole shopping cart into my own website. I have a form in my website whereby the admin can upload products which get sent to the database and also show up on the website for the users to view. the problem i am having is with the images. in the tutorial, the images have been manually entered in the mysql database.

I have a form as follows:

```
    <form action="productsadded.php" method="post">

<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="name">Product Name:</label>
</td>
    <td><span id="sprytextfield1">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Enter Products Name</span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="description">Description: </label>
</td>
    <td><span id="sprytextarea1">
      <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
      <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">Enter Products Description</span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>    <label for="price">Price: </label>
</td>
    <td><span id="sprytextfield2">
    <input type="text" name="price" id="price" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Enter Price</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Numbers Only</span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="price">Image: </label></td>
    <td><input name="picture" id="picture" accept="image/jpeg" type="file" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input name="" type="submit" value="Add Product" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

the productsadded page is as follows:

```
  <?php


$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$description = $_REQUEST['description'];
$price = $_REQUEST['price'];
$picture = $_REQUEST['picture'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","*****","*****");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('jahedhus_91', $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, picture) VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$price', '$picture')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

the problem i am having is that once a product is added to the database, the image of the product is not shown on the website. the name, details & price of the products are being shown except the image.

the sql statement for product info to be shown are as follows:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2px" width="600px">
    <?
        $result=mysql_query("select * from products");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    ?>
<tr>
    <td><img src=<?=$row['picture']?> /></td>
    <td>    <b><a href="products.php?product_id=<?=$row['serial']?>"><?=$row['name']?></a></b><br />
            <?=$row['description']?><br />
            Price:<big style="color:green">
                £<?=$row['price']?></big><br /><br />
            <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?=$row['serial']?>)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><hr size="1" /></td>
<? } ?>
```

sorry for the really long post, any suggesstions will be helpful.

thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to save the contents of the picture (the data) into the database, or are you trying to save just a name. Your code's intent is conflicting about which you want to do.

Comment: i want to save the image into the database

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I notice you don't have enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag.

```
<form action="productsadded.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

On second glance, I notice that you're attempting to store the image directly in the database with `$_REQUEST['picture']`. It won't work like that. It really depends on how the shopping cart is referencing the images in the database. Is it simply a filename? in which case, you'll need to use something like:

```
$target_path = 'path/to/images/'.basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']); 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
```

and save the `$target_path` in the database as the picture. This will move the uploaded file into the product images directory.

I'd recommend you follow some tutorials on php file upload separately from this shopping cart and get the hang of it first.

Edit: Just noticed the comment that you want to store the image in the database. This is more complicated but this looks like a good tutorial: http://www.phpriot.com/articles/storing-images-in-mysql

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, but where do i actually put this line of code: $target_path = 'path/to/images/'.basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']); 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target_path);

Comment: You can't just copy the code in, you'll need to figure out where the product images are stored currently and also how the url to them is stored in the database. But it can go instead of `$picture = $_REQUEST['picture'];`. and instead of inserting `$picture` into the database, insert the url to the image.

Comment: i am so lost atm. i have an error coming up:                  Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/13092011152.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/jahedhus/public_html/music/admin/productsadded.php on line 78

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpiiTE22' to 'images/13092011152.jpg' in /home/jahedhus/public_html/music/admin/productsadded.php on line 78